# How to get back the ownership from crowdsale?

Tags: truffle, erc-20, crowdsale, truffle-migration, openzeppelin-contracts

When I started crowdsale, I transferred token ownership to the crowdsale contract. When the sale finished, I'd like to send back the ownership to token so that the next crowdsale will start. How can I do that? I guess I can use `FinalizableCrowdsale` for defining those functions, but I have no idea how to get the token address in the contract and how to define the `finalize()` function... help me..

Actually, the contract was working well, but after finishing the crowdsale, the `finalize()` that I defined in the contract didn't work which means the ownership was not transferred. Should I call the function manually?

**Crowdsale.sol**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "./DappToken.sol";

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/FinalizableCrowdsale.sol";
// import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/WhitelistedCrowdsale.sol";

contract DappTokenCrowdsale is Crowdsale, MintedCrowdsale, CappedCrowdsale, TimedCrowdsale, FinalizableCrowdsale {
    DappToken private token;
    address tokenAddress;
    address crowdsaleOwner;

    bool public isFinalized = false;

    constructor(
      uint256 _rate,
      address _wallet,
      DappToken _token,
      uint256 _cap,
      uint256 _openingTime,
      uint256 _closingTime
    )
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)
    public
    {
      token = _token;
      crowdsaleOwner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == crowdsaleOwner); // Only the owner of the crowdsale contract should be able to call this function.
        // I assume the crowdsale contract holds a reference to the token contract.
        token.transferOwnership(_newOwner);
    }

    function finalize() onlyOwner public {
      require(!isFinalized);
      require(hasClosed());

      transferOwnership(token);

      finalization();
      emit Finalized();

      isFinalized = true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What does your `MintableToken` look like? If your `MintableToken` is the basic OpenZeppelin's token contract, then it inherits from `Ownable` and has the `transferOWnership` function which you can call. You seem to be missing an import for it at least?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Ah, I just editted the code, and updated the question. the error has gone, but finalize() function didn't work T-T.. Should I call the function manually?? I thought, the contract inherited FinalizableCrowdsale, and I re-defined finalize() function on my contract. So, it gonna be working when the crowdsale finished, but it was not...

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I verified the code on the Etherscan and tried to call that function manually, but it was failed. I guess, the MetaMask that I logged on is not an owner of the contract.. How can I call it? currently, the owner of the token is an address of crowdsale.

Comment: `transferOwnership` can only be called by the owner, otherwise anyone could claim ownership. The crowdsale address would have to call it

Comment: @UnhaBack If you called `finalize()` then you are executing `transferOwnership(token)` which will execute `token.transferOwnership(token)` setting itself as its owner. If you are using OpenZeppelin contracts then unless the token was modified to handle this case you will not be able to change the owner again.